# Gazebo 3.0 linking error

Tags: gazebo-3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When compiling an executable for Gazebo 3.0, I get the following linking error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lDepthCameraPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGpuRayPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRayPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lContactPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCameraPlugin
```

I see that @hsu had the same issue and fixed it for Gazebo 1.9:
[pull-request 616](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/616/export-gazebo-lib-dirs-and-plugin-lib-dirs/diff#chg-cmake/gazebo-config.cmake.in)

I compiled Gazebo 3.0 from source following [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/2.0/install) tutorial.

Here is the output from: dpkg -l gazebo | grep gazebo

```
ii  gazebo      1.9.5-1~precise      Gazebo simulator - Main package
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6112/gazebo-3.0-linking-error/) by [isura](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115/isura/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-02**:
Could you please update the answer with the output of: dpkg -l gazebo | grep gazebo?

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115/isura/) on 2014-05-04**:
I compiled Gazebo 3.0 from source following [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/2.0/install) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Got rid of the error by removing gazebo_ros from find_package inside CMakeLists.

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115/isura/) with karma: 55 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0